# WooCommerce Subscription - possible to detect whether a subscription is deactivated?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm using WooCommerce Subscriptions and Automatewoo and I'm trying to pass on all subscriptions details and a few custom ones to a 3rd party API.

Is it possible to determine whether or not a subscription was deactivated (and possibly reactivated) by the user or the administrator (ie changing an order via wp-admin)? I currently determine this by having a workflow that fires based on the note left on the subscription which details user or admin status updates. But if I'm syncing all orders across out of context, I need to be able to get this information from the subscription directly.

```
if ( $substatus = $workflow->data_layer()->get_subscription()->get_data()['status'] ) {
     .... // just returns 'on-hold', 'active' etc...
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the answer.?

Answer (score 1):

```
'suspension_count'   => $subscription->get_suspension_count()
```

*This will let you know if the subscription is deactivated ever.*

You can see the function inside subscription class

```
/**
 * Get suspension count.
 *
 * @return int
 * @since 2.2.0
 */
public function get_suspension_count( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_prop( 'suspension_count', $context );
}
```